# Nestjs TypeORM syntax error at or near "AND"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am building a UserService class in my system, and declaring which should be a simple 'find' method, but I'm receiving the error as shown in the image bellow:

[image: TypeORM syntax error at or near "AND"]

This is my `service` method:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
...
async findByRA(academicRegister: string) {
    return await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: { academicRegister: academicRegister },
    });
  }
...
}
```

This is my `controller`:

```js
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
...
@Get('ra/:ra')
  findByRa(@Param('ra') ra: string) {
    return this.usersService.findByRA(ra);
  }
...
}
```

This is my `User` entity, and if I change `eager` to `false`, the error does not happen, however I don't get the data from the child entities, which I need

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  @ApiProperty({ enum: UserRole, enumName: 'UserRole' })
  userRole: UserRole;

  @Column()
  academicRegister: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Coordinator, (coordinator) => coordinator.user, {
    eager: true,
    nullable: true,
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove', 'recover'],
  })
  coordinator?: Coordinator;

  @OneToOne(() => Monitor, (monitor) => monitor.user, {
    eager: true,
    nullable: true,
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove', 'recover'],
  })
  monitor?: Monitor;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creationDate: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletionDate?: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  deletedBy?: string;
}
```

These are the related columns in the child entities:

```js
export class Coordinator {
...
  @Column({ nullable: true, unique: true })
  userId: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.coordinator, {
    orphanedRowAction: 'nullify',
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove', 'recover'],
  })
  user: User;
...
}
```

```js
export class Monitor {
...
  @Column({ nullable: true, unique: true })
  userId: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.monitor, {
    orphanedRowAction: 'nullify',
    cascade: ['insert', 'update', 'soft-remove', 'recover'],
  })
  user: User;
...
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of exceptions, but rather the content

Answer (score 0):

> Eager relations are loaded automatically each time you load entities
> from the database.

When You will be loading your `Coordinator` or `Monitor` entity you don't need to have manually call for your relations it will be done automatically.

You must be accessing your entities in wrong way.

Comment: Try changing your code if you understand what it means, or just show the code how you are accessing your relations.